# Is it safe to remove SAL annotations from Code?

Tags: c++, annotations, sal

I am porting some code from Visual Studio to Mingw gcc.
I noticed that in that code a lot of annotations such as

```
__field_ecount_opt
AM_NOVTABLE
_out_bcount_part_opt(x,y)
```

are being used. I came across this thread which talks about [SAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239809/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-out-in-opt-allowed-how-do-they-work-should) annotations.

My question is if I remove the some SAL Annotations from my code. Will it have any negative effects ? Will the code still be functional ?

Answer (score 1):

The code will still be functional. You will just lose the benefit of having static code analysis performed on the code, so it might be easier to overlook bugs that could be caught at compile time.

Comment: More resources about SAL annotations: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182032.aspx